# Is it possible to encode one stream with serveral codecs

Tags: ffmpeg

For example making JPGs of a x264 encoding such as

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -c:v mjpeg preview.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

The most basic command is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output1.mp4 output2_%03d.jpg
```

This will result in the `output1.mp4` video and a series of JPG images named `output2_001.jpg`, `output2_002.jpg`, `output2_003.jpg`, etc.

Comment: Does this mean the jpg images will be screenshots of the encoded output.mp4?

Comment: @FallingSnow No. It will decode `input.mp4` into raw video, then encode the raw video into JPG. If you want image outputs derived from `output1.mp4` then the most simple solution is to just run `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output1.mp4` then `ffmpeg -i output1.mp4 output2_%03d.jpg`. I don't know why you would want to do that though as `output1.mp4` is lossy and so is `output2_%03d.jpg`. Perhaps I misunderstood what you wanted to do. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @LordNechbeard I am trying to create preview images of the output while encoding it. That way I don't have to run another ffmpeg instance after the video encoding has finished. Lossy output doesn't matter to me, these are just preview thumbnails and lowest file size is my goal.

Comment: @FallingSnow This answers your question as written. Maybe ask a new one with all the details?